# Is there a way for a user to have an alias?

Tags: security

In the 80s I was the owner of a Apple support BBS (single user/one phone line).

I created a way for a user to have an alias linked to their user account.

The alias had the ability to post and any replies/responses were received in the users account and the user was provided the opportunity to respond as the alias or under their actual username.

If the user decided or accidently attempted to respond using their actual username they were warned. This was a feature enjoyed by many of my users.

Is there a way to incorporate this feature in Wordpress either by plugin or hard coding?

Thank you for your support,

Greg

Comment: could you explain why you want to this, beyond the simple fact of masking/aliasing your user's identity in the front-end.  Do alias have less capabilities/access that the actual account?  What differentiates the user account from the alias?

Answer (score 2):

Users are means of authentication and authorization. This should not be confused in any way with whatever information is displayed on the front end.

By default wordpress core is guilty of not understanding the distinction, but in some contexts like comments it should be easy to add a "name" field to the comment form for logged in users, and use it for display. Other contexts like author archives will be hard to adjust to handling multiple "handles" for users and the easiest path would be to simply create an additional user.

Adjusting functionality of plugins most likely will be a matter of hit and miss, most likely mostly miss.

Tl;Dr;

Just create a second user, maybe install one of the user switchers plugins for easy switching when needed.

Comment: Thanks for replying but it's not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: ok, will simplify it - the answer is "no"